# Get and process entire row in ddply in a function

Tags: r, plyr

It's easy to grab one or more in ddply to process, but is there a way to grab the entire current row and pass that onto a function? Or to grab a set of columns determined at runtime?

Let me illustrate:

Given a dataframe like

```
df = data.frame(a=seq(1,20), b=seq(1,5), c= seq(5,1))
df
    a b c
1   1 1 5
2   2 2 4
3   3 3 3
```

I could write a function to sum named columns along a row of a data frame like this:

```
selectiveSummer = function(row,colsToSum) {
   return(sum(row[,colsToSum])) 
}
```

It works when I call it for a row like this:

```
> selectiveSummer(df[1,],c('a','c'))
[1] 6
```

So I'd like to wrap that in an anonymous function and use it in ddply to apply it to every row in the table, something like the example below

```
f = function(x) { selectiveSummer(x,c('a','c')) }
#this doesn't work!
ddply(df,.(a,b,c), transform, foo=f(row))
```

I'd like to find a solution where the set of columns to manipulate can be determined at runtime, so if there's some way just to splat that from ddply's args and pass it into a function that takes any number of args, that works too.

Edit: To be clear, the real application driving this isn't sum, but this was an easier explanation

Comment: Thanks, that works for this example - If, however I have extra columns that aren't in the group that I'd like to preserve, is there a way to do this with more transform/mutate-like behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only select single rows with ddply if rows can be identified in a unique way with one or more variables. If there are identical rows ddply will cycle over data frames of multiple rows even if you use all columns (like `ddply(df, names(df), f`).

Why not use apply instead? Apply does iterate over individual rows.

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) f(as.data.frame(t(x)))))
```

result:

```
[1]  6  6  6  6  6 11 11 11 11 11 16 16 16 16 16 21 21 21 21 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple...

```
df$id = 1:nrow(df)
ddply(df,c('id'),function(x){ ... })
```

OR

```
adply(df,1,function(x){ ... })
```